# Ylabel too distant from axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

I'd like to insert a tikz picture in a beamer document.
When I plot the image the distance from ylabel and the axis is too large, so the picture is too small.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{.55\textwidth}
     \begin{block}<1->{One}
        text
     \end{block}
     \begin{block}<2->{Two}
        text
     \end{block}
     \begin{block}<3->{Three}
        text
     \end{block}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [scaled ticks=false, tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed}, xlabel={\tiny$C_D$}, ylabel={\tiny$C_L$}, domain=-1.5:1.5, width=\textwidth]
    \addplot [black] ({0.0114 + 0.03435*\x*\x}, {\x});
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
     \begin{block}<1->{One}
        text text text text text text text text text text text
     \end{block}
     \begin{block}<2->{Two}
        text
     \end{block}
     \begin{block}<3->{Three}
        text
     \end{block}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
  width=\linewidth,
  scaled ticks=false, 
  tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed,font=\tiny}, 
  xlabel={\tiny $C_D$}, 
  ylabel={\tiny $C_L$},
  domain=-1.5:1.5
                ]
    \addplot [black] ({0.0114 + 0.03435*\x*\x}, {\x});
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

if it is enough better ...

[image]

As you can see, I add `compat=1.13` option in common `\pgfplotsset` and from it remove `every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny}`. Font size I determined locally in `tick label style={...}`.

Comment: You can also use `ylabel near ticks, ylabel shift={-10pt},` if you want a tighter positioning.

Comment: @Rmano, yes, this is the next step if obtained result to OP is not  satisfactory.